# How do I set a custom thumbnailer for audio/x-vorbis+org?

Tags: 11.04, gconf, mime-type

Google shows this error referenced on some Thunderbird bug, but it's not clear to me how they resolve it.

Here is my issue:

I have vorbis file:

`xdg-mime query filetype "my-file1.ogg"`

→ output: `x-vorbis+ogg`

`xdg-mime query filetype "my-file2.oga"`

→ output: `x-vorbis+ogg`

I tried to add a key in gconf with gconftool-2 using above mime-type (`x-vorbis+ogg`) and I got this error:

> `+' is an invalid character in key/directory names

If I ignore reported mime-type by xdg-mime and instead use simple mime-type for vorbis - `ogg`, then the key works only for files with extension ".oga" but not with more common extension ".ogg"

What to do? Is it possible to escape 'plus' sign in reported vorbis mime-type when passing to gconftool-2? Is this but in gconftool-2?

Comment: have you tried "@ogg"

Comment: @htorque: It doesn't matter where, try to add key name with "+" anywhere it won't work. It seems like misfortune naming of mime-type here, although I don't know if maybe "+" can be escaped

Comment: @BlueXrider: yes

Comment: I'm trying to make handler in '/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/audio@mime/' for vorbis files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace characters like "/" and "+" with "@". This is working fine here on a freshly installed 11.04 VM:

- Open the `gconf-editor` and go to */desktop/gnome/thumbnailers*.
- There should already be an entry for `audio@x-vorbis@ogg`.
- Just paste the path to your thumbnailer for *command*, e.g.

  ```
  /home/YOUR_USER/bin/my-ogg-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
  ```

  and set *enable* to true.

This will work for .ogg files, for .oga files do the same for the `audio@ogg` thumbnailer entry.

---

If you've messed up too much with thumbnailers and want a fresh start (will undo **all** thumbnailer customization):

```
rm -rf ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers
```